# Access Default Value with Today's Date specified time

Tags: vba, ms-access

Real quick question.
I'm trying to set a default value in an Access table that gives me today's date and 8AM as the time.

I attempted to use `=Date() & "8:00:00 AM"` but I am getting a type mismatch error. I changed the format of the column to General Date to be able to have date and time but still no go.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build the desired date like that

```
dt = Date
dt = DateSerial(Year(dt), Month(dt), Day(dt))
dt = dt + TimeSerial(8, 0, 0)
```

A date is a number, 2020/02/08 is 44600. A time is a fraction, 8am is  0,333333333333333. If you want to build a date like *Today 8 am* you need to use the build-in functions Dateserial and Timeserial which gives you excatly the date you need.

Comment: perfect thank you!

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Why not just `dt = Date + TimeSerial(8, 0, 0)` ?

Comment: Yes, works as well, of course.  See my comments above

Answer (score 2):

You were nearly there. A date isn't a string, so you add time with `+` and delimit with `#`:

```
=Date() + #8:00:00 AM#
```

Of course, building with parts is fine too but a little too overcomplicated imo

Comment: On the one hand I agree on the other side I (hopefully) showed the OP how to build a lot of dates like for example the first day of the current month.

Comment: Well... Yes, but the question is just how to add time to a date, and simpler is often better (easier to read, faster, etc.)

Comment: Again, right, but _#8:00:00 AM#_ will be casted by VBA, I guess. So, your code includes some implicit stuff which isn't obvious and also has an impact on performance (can very likey be neglected) and readability.

Comment: @Storax: No reason to guess. `#08:00:00 AM#` _is_ a date value, so nothing to cast.